# Why is the antimatter question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

[Antimatter Storage](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17323/antimatter-storage) is currently on hold as off-topic.  It has comments suggesting it be moved to Physics.  It also has three reopen votes.

It's not clear to me why it's off-topic.  Merely *also* being on-topic somewhere else isn't a reason to migrate, but if it's truly off-topic here then we should help the author by migrating it.

If this question is off-topic, why?  If it's not, should it be reopened?

Comment: *At a glance,* the question seems to be "if I had a reasonably large quantity of antimatter, and was proposing this method of containing it in our matter-based world, would the method of containment work?". That does appear to be more along the lines of Physics than Worldbuilding to me. Now that you've brought it up, though, definitely let's hear from the community on this.

Comment: It's now re-opened.

Answer (score 10):

I did the recent (extensive) edit and voted to reopen.

In my view, it is a hard science question, not so different from, say [How to create a nuclear explosion localized to only a few square feet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/how-to-create-a-nuclear-explosion-localized-to-only-a-few-square-feet)

The thing that makes this one tricky, I think, is the [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) tag. If it didn't have that, the question would definitely be on topic and a good fit here and not on physics: "I have an idea, what physics do we need to make it work?"

As it stands, I think it's a better fit for physics. But I can see how this question could, with a bit of story padding, be about building a world: "In my world, they use antimatter as power source, and the containment field is going to break. Their system acts like such and such. Is this plausible?" While that might not be a great question, it certainly looks more on topic.

Since antimatter storage is a part of so many sci-fi worlds, I think this is a good look at a possible method to explain how it can work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Perhaps I should remove the reality-check tag? Or is it sufficient? I may try to rephrase the question once more, and i'll do my best to make it on-topic. Again, thanks for your (extensive) edits.